# Do I need a Transit visa in Delhi for an onward journey?

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, afghan-citizens

I am an Afghan citizen travelling to Sri Lanka from Kabul. I have a layover at Delhi Airport with a flight change. Please let me know in case i need a transit visa.

Comment: Do you have separate tickets or a single booking?

Comment: On a single booking two different PNRs for two different airline and only cabin luggage. The Layover is for 4 hrs

Answer (score 2):

A visa is not required, if the trip was made on the same booking, you transit within 24 hours and stay within the transit area:

> A visa is not required to transit only if you will remain within the transit area reserved for international transit passengers for the duration of time you are in an Indian Airport and you will not pass through immigration.

([Source](https://india.travisa.com/VisaInstructions.aspx?CitizenshipID=US&CountryID=IN&TravelerTypeID=TR&ResidenceID=US&PartnerID=TA))

Note: If collecting bags, you will need a visa:

> You have to pass immigration to collect bags so will need a visa. Ideally you need to check your bags through to your final destination so you can remain in transit in Delhi.

([Source](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-indian-subcontinent/india/indian-delhi-airport-transit-question-90003310-b05c-42aa-a035-26785c992fc9))